# Homes needed in June

Tags: cats, adoption

My "abandoned kitty" of poss under 12 months ,moved in and now has 3 adorable kittens. So what do I do. Mum trusts me and now I adore her. Help. Need to home the 3 in Orihuela Costa Spain. They will be used to being handled and house trained as mum is so loving !

Comment: It looks like you need an advertising board but unfortunately this site isn't that. Maybe Quora or reddit allow these kind of requests. On Pets.se they are off-topic, not allowed. Please visit the [help] if you want to read more background on the site policies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Found 4 kittens in a bush in my side yard, don't know what to do](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6386/found-4-kittens-in-a-bush-in-my-side-yard-dont-know-what-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

Contact your local animal or cat rescues. They can help you find homes for your cats. Some rescues will travel, so even if you don't have any that are very close to you, contact whichever ones are closest. If they can't help they might know another rescue who can. If the first rescue you contact can't help you, try another one.

Alternatively, keep them. Four cats is a lot, but doable, although the vet bills can be hard to manage when you need to get them all fixed.

No matter what, make sure you take mum to the vet and get her spayed so there will be no more kittens to rehome.

Comment: Beta see conversation in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43899317#43899317